# Update Div/PartialView on Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this which makes an Ajax call and returns a result and works perfectly.

```
@foreach (var fighter in Model.Fighters)
{
@Ajax.ActionLink(fighter.FirstName + " " + fighter.LastName, "ShowResults",new            {id        =fighter.FighterID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "SuccessFunction", UpdateTargetId = "results" })
}
<div id="results">
@Html.Partial("Partial1", Model)
</div>

 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ShowResults(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Id = id;
        Fight fight = db.Fights.Find(id);
        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "The ID is: " + id;
            return PartialView("Partial1", fight);
        }
        return View(fight);
    }
```

However I'm trying to do the same thing but for the partial view to be reloaded on a set interval. I trued to do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#round").load("/Fight/ShowResults");

    setInterval(function () {
        $("#results").load("/Fight/ShowResults");
    }, 100000); //Refreshes every 30 seconds

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });  //Turn off caching
});
</script>
```

But doesnt seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: 100 seconds is  closely 2 mins

Comment: Yeah, thats a typo. I tried it on 1 second on the application and nothing happened.

Comment: try setting up your ajax first. Also have a scan of the API; I believe some of the aliased Ajax methods ignore setup, and load might be one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, I had a number of problems that I needed to fix. I should've looked at it closer before asking. The reason that this wouldn't run was because I needed to create a script section in the layout page as I was trying to run this script of the RenderBody section.